# Hardcode input file

Tags: awk

Given this script

```
#!/bin/awk -f
{
  print $1
}
```

It can be called like so

```
foo.awk foo.txt
```

However I would like the script to always call `foo.txt`. So I would like to modify the script so that it can be called without the input file, like this

```
foo.awk
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {ARGV[ARGC++] = "foo.txt"}
{print $1}
```

This will add `foo.txt` to the end of the arguments list, as if you had put it there on the command line.  This has the added bonus of allowing you to extend your script to do more than just print, without having to put everything in the `BEGIN` block.

Answer (score 0):

ok, do this trick maybe? (cheat?)

```
#!/bin/sh
awk '{print $1}' foo.txt
```

you could name it as `foo.awk`

and then

```
chmod +x foo.awk
```

now try `./foo.awk` under same directory.

**EDIT**

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{while(getline < "/path/to/foo.txt")print $1 }
```

strange requirement. why bash wrapper doesn't fit your requirement? You did tag the question with `shell`
anyway, the above script should be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a shell wrapper for this:

```
#!/bin/bash
foo.awk foo.txt
```